# C# Read Sub Elements with XMLReader(?)

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm currently struggeling with reading Sub-Elements from Sub-Elements. What would be the best way to read a XML structured like that:

```
<network>
<channel type="...">
        <sub1.1>...</sub1.1>
        <sub1.2>...</sub1.2>
        ...
</channel>

<channel type="...">
        <sub1.1>...</sub1.1>
        <sub1.2>...</sub1.2>
        ...
</channel>
...

<group number="...">
        <sub2.1>...</sub2.1>
        <sub2.2>...</sub2.2>
        ...
</group>
...

<group number="...">
        <sub2.1>...</sub2.1>
        <sub2.2>...</sub2.2>
        ...
</group>
...

<gateway id="...">
        <sub3.1>...</sub3.1>
        <sub3.2>...</sub3.2>
        <sub3.3>
                <sub3.3.1>...</sub3.3.1>
        </sub3.3>
        <sub3.4>
                <sub3.4.1>...</sub3.4.1>
        </sub3.4>
...
</gateway>
...
<network>
```

I would like to read the Attributes like type, number, id... and also all the sub elements and sub-sub elements. I tried it with XMLReader but struggled with getting sub-sub elements etc...

If someone could help me with getting me an approach I would be very thankful.

Comment: MSDN XMLReader documentation is pretty good. Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-perform-streaming-transform-of-large-xml-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MoveToFirstElementAttribute()` and `MoveToNextAttribute()` to get attribute's name (and it's values)

```
string fileName = @"C:\file.xml";

using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName)) //using System.Xml
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace || reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) continue;
                Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                string message = $"Position: {reader.LineNumber},{reader.LinePosition}\tNode Type: {reader.NodeType.ToString()}\tDepth: {reader.Depth}\n";
                if (reader.Name.Trim() != "") message += $"Name: {reader.Name}\t";
                if (reader.Value.Trim() != "") message += $"Value: {reader.Value}\t";
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                // Read() method doesn't get into attribute nodes, so check them manually then get them by MoveToFirstElementAttribute() and MoveToNextAttribute() methods
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nHas {reader.AttributeCount} Attribute(s):\n");
                    reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Attribute Name: {reader.Name}\tValue: {reader.Value}");
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Attribute Name: {reader.Name}\tValue: {reader.Value}");
                    }
                    reader.MoveToElement();
                }
            }
        }
```

I used **XmlTextReader** (which is child class of **XmlReader**) because it includes line infos. if you want to use **XmlReader** then you can replace it with **XmlTextReader** *(except **XmlReader** doesn't have **LineNumber** and **LinePosition** properties)*

You can also check the "sub-ness" of an element by `Depth` property. Keep in mind that `Depth` starts from 0 (the outmost elements **Depth** value will be **0**)